# How to handle one-way (in-only) soap messages

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've created a proxy service in the ESB that is calling in-only soap operations. (So only an input message). The backend soap service responds with a HTTP 202/Accepted response with no content in the response. As far as I know, this is correct behavior for in-only operations.

When I call the the service via the ESB proxy service I keep getting errors in the logs:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperation.getMessage(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:124)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processResponse(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:125)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>       at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I've tried setting the OUT_ONLY property, FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED but the error persists. It seems that the ESB soap sender is not able to handle this scenario correctly.

Any idea how to handle this? I'm not able to change anything about the backend service.

Comment: Are you sure your backend service responds only the HTTP status code only? I mean no response body?

Comment: You really should use tcpmon between the ESB and your service and have a look at it's response...

Comment: I've checked with TCPMon. This is the response header from the backend: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 08 Apr 2015 09:23:44 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server

Comment: I've tried the same scenario inside ESB 4.8.1, with passthrough and nio http transport, without any problem. Which version of WSO2 ESB are you using ?

Comment: 4.8.1. Can you share your config. I must be overlooking something.

Comment: Update: I've done a new and clean installation and now it works! Big difference: My old config was running in multi-tenant mode and the proxy services were running in the tenant. This seems to me that this might be a bug.